# django restframwork Put and DELETE doesn't work

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views, request

Get and post work pretty well for me .
but put and delete i use "U_repo_name" to look in table
i got the error message :

Page not found (404)
Request Method: PUT
Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/gitapi/repo/authoo/
Using the URLconf defined in gitit.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

admin/
gitapi/ [name='gitapi']
gitapi/ repo/
gitapi/ repo/str:U_repo_name

this is my model :

```
class UserRepos(models.Model):
    U_repo_name =models.CharField( max_length=50)
```

this is my url :

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('repo/',view=userreposapi),
    path('repo/<str:U_repo_name>',view=userreposapi),
]
```

project urls :

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('gitapi/',include('gitapi.urls')),
]
```

this is my serializer :

```
class UserReposSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = UserRepos
        fields ='__all__'
```

and this is my views :

```
@csrf_exempt
def userreposapi(request,id=0):
    if request.method=='GET':
        userrepos = UserRepos.objects.all()
        userreposserializer = UserReposSerializer(userrepos , many=True)
        return JsonResponse(userreposserializer.data , safe=False)

    elif request.method=='POST':
        userrepos_data=JSONParser().parse(request)
        userreposerializer = UserReposSerializer(data=userrepos_data)
        if userreposerializer.is_valid():
            userreposerializer.save()
            return JsonResponse("added successfully!!",safe=False)
        return JsonResponse("failed to add",safe=False)
    
    elif request.method=='Put':
        userrepos_data=JSONParser().parse(request)
        userrepos = UserRepos.objects.get(U_repo_name=userrepos_data['U_repo_name'])
        userreposserializer=UserReposSerializer(userrepos,data=userrepos_data)
        if userreposserializer.is_valid():
            userreposserializer.save()
            return JsonResponse("updated successfully", safe=False)
        return JsonResponse("failed to update",safe=False)


    elif request.method=='DELETE':
        userrepos = UserRepos.objects.all()
        userrepos.delete()
        return JsonResponse("deleted",safe=False)
```

Comment: Can you share the gitapi path code snippet?

Comment: @YedidyaRashi i did update the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi! I see a few issues with your code that might be causing this problem.

1. `request.method` is always full capitalized, so you should use the string `'PUT'` instead of `'Put'` on this line:

   ```python
   elif request.method=='Put':
   ```
2. You are adding a trailing slash to your route when trying to access it (/gitapi/repo/authoo**/**), but the pattern set in `urlpatterns` doesn't have this trailing slash:

   ```python
   path('repo/<str:U_repo_name>',view=userreposapi),
   ```

   You can use [`re_path()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/urls/#re-path) instead of `path()` to set a regex URL pattern that works whether you add a trailing slash or not:

   ```python
   re_path(r'repo/(?P<U_repo_name>\w+)/?', view=userreposapi),
   ```

   `(?P<U_repo_name>\w+)` creates a named group called `U_repo_name` that matches any word character (`[a-zA-Z0-9_]`) from one to more times. `/?` matches a single optional `/`.
3. Your route `'repo/<str:U_repo_name>'` captures a string in the variable `U_repo_name`. This variable is provided to the view `userreposapi()` as a keyword argument, but the view currently only accepts the `id` kwarg. You should either add the `U_repo_name` kwarg as an optional argument or make the view accept other keyword arguments with `**kwargs`:

   ```python
   # Both are valid:
   def userreposapi(request, id=0, U_repo_name=None):
       ...
   def userreposapi(request, id=0, **kwargs):
       ...
   ```

Fixing these 3 issues should make the route work.

Answer (score 0):

I think the trailing slash in the url is the problem. I should be not there.

```
http://localhost:8000/gitapi/repo/authoo  # here I removed the trailing slash.
```